# Google Chart Issue - Only the Wireframe is Visible

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, google-visualization

I am integrating several chart utilities in order to display a collection of analysis and statistics information in a web page.
I am using following technologies/components to implement those visualizations.

#### D3

Use to display word cloud, ontology views, etc.

#### Google Charts

Mainly used to display statistical information.

#### Jason Davies Word Tree (based on D3)

Use to display a word tree analysis service.

I am coming across an issue which had heavily impacted to my progress.
The google visualizations showing the details, but it did not colour it's visualizations. Only the wire frame is visible. I am including an image for your reference.

Don't know whether having multiple visualizations in a single web page causing all these issue.

If anyone can give a helpful hint to get over with the issue, would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

I cannot upload related images as I do not have sufficient reputations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got resolved after two resolution actions.

Thanks to nice post  here, I managed to resolve the Google chart library loading issue before the actual bootstrapping comes into the action.
This can be resolved by adding this code segment.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['setuAnalysis']);
});

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
```

In addition to that, there were some conflicts with the CSS styles I introduced together with some of the controls embedded. Specially, the styles introduced by Angular Tree view conflicts with Google chart rendering.

Finally managed to resolve both issues.